# LWC: How to stylize icon inside lightning-button

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

Is there any way to stylize only the icon in a lightning-button?

```
<lightning-button variant="base" label="Base" icon-name="utility:add" icon-position="right"></lightning-button>
```

I only want to edit the styling on the add symbol and not the entire button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Styling Hooks](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/platforms/lightning/styling-hooks/) as below to change the size and color of the Icon.

```
.custom-css {
    --lwc-squareIconMediumContentAlt:2rem;
    --slds-c-icon-color-foreground:green; 
}

<lightning-button variant="base" label="Base" class="custom-css" icon-name="utility:add" icon-position="right"></lightning-button>
```

Comment: Is there anywhere where I can find documentation about --slds-c-icon-color-foreground that doesnt look like standard attributes, and they are not mention in SLDS or in the LWC component library

Comment: `--slds-c-icon-color-foreground` is a standard attribute mentioned in the official Lightning Design System documentation. Please check this link https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/buttons/.